# Finding Height of OpenGL ES Object in Pixels

Tags: java, android, opengl-es

I have an OpenGL ES 2.0 Surface in my Android app that contains an object that represents the background in this view space. I want to find out how I can determine the height of this entire object, including the portion below the screen, in either pixels or dp. The object itself is an instance of a sprite class I made that takes in view parameters in it's constructor.

Ultimately, I want this height data so I can create a button in a parallel layout that has the exact same height as the entire OpenGL sprite object (including the off-screen portion).

What i've tried:

- Using the height of the texture image used by the sprite: This doesn't work for somewhat obvious reasons. The image is 2048px tall but this is not the height of the sprite object it is laid atop within the openGL view, the units are different as well it seems (world space vs eye space, etc.)
- Using the height of the rectangle the sprite is instantiated with: This doesn't work because I'm not sure how to work around the unit mismatch. My rect object that I feed into my sprite constructor has the following parameters: RectF(-3.0, -6.926641, 3.0, 41.07336), where -6.9 & 41 represent the top and bottom of the sprite in my OpenGL view. If I make my button ~48 dp or px tall it of course won't match the height of the sprite that is rendered on my device screen. This is again because the units are mismatched, the button uses density independent pixels while the sprite boundaries use some other unit.

How can I find the height value I seek? It would be preferable to get this value in dp to allow for easy 1:1 mapping with my button's layout params, but I get the feeling that i will have to get this value from the OpenGL pipeline in px and then convert to dp manually.

Code below (I left out a lot because I don't want to drown you all in 1000s of lines of unrelated logic. If I left out anything that would help your understanding please let me know and I can add it.)

**OpenGL Renderer**
    public class OpenGL_GLRenderer implements GLSurfaceView.Renderer {

```
private int catNum = 0;
private OpenGL_FloatAnimator scroller;
private float offset = 0.0f;
private int frameHeight, frameWidth;    //height and width of the screen. Used for ortho view configuration
private float orthoTop, orthoBottom;

private final Context mActivityContext;
//texture objects

private OpenGL_TextureData catBoardTexture;
private OpenGL_SpriteClass catBoard; //sprite objects for background shape


/**
 * Store the model matrix. This matrix is used to move models from object space (where each model can be thought
 * of being located at the center of the universe) to world space.
 */
private float[] mModelMatrix = new float[16];

/**
 * Store the view matrix. This can be thought of as our camera. This matrix transforms world space to eye space;
 * it positions things relative to our eye.
 */
private float[] mViewMatrix = new float[16];

/** Store the projection matrix. This is used to project the scene onto a 2D viewport. */
private float[] mProjectionMatrix = new float[16];

/** Allocate storage for the final combined matrix. This will be passed into the shader program. */
private float[] mMVPMatrix = new float[16];

/** This will be used to pass in the transformation matrix. */
private int mMVPMatrixHandle;

/** This will be used to pass in the modelview matrix. */
private int mMVMatrixHandle;

/** This will be used to pass in model position information. */
private int mPositionHandle;

/** This will be used to pass in model color information. */
private int mColorHandle;

/** This will be used to pass in model normal information. */
private int mNormalHandle;

/** This will be used to pass in the texture. */
private int mTextureUniformHandle;

/** This will be used to pass in model texture coordinate information. */
private int mTextureCoordinateHandle;


/** This is a handle to our per-vertex cube shading program. */
private int catBoardProgramHandle;

/**
 * Initialize the model data.
 */
public OpenGL_GLRenderer(final Context context)
{
    mActivityContext = context;
    scroller = new OpenGL_FloatAnimator();//screen scroll animation object
}

protected string getVertexShader(int resourceID) {
    return OpenGL_RawResourceReader.readTextFileFromRawResource(mActivityContext, resourceID);
}

protected string getFragmentShader(int resourceID) {
    return OpenGL_RawResourceReader.readTextFileFromRawResource(mActivityContext, resourceID);
}

@Override
public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 glUnused, EGLConfig config) {
    GLES20.glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);    // Set the background clear color to black.
    GLES20.glEnable(GLES20.GL_BLEND);              //Enable blending
    GLES20.glBlendFunc(GLES20.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GLES20.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

    // Enable depth testing
    GLES20.glEnable(GLES20.GL_DEPTH_TEST);

    Matrix.setIdentityM(mViewMatrix, 0);

    //*************Shader Setup****************************
    //set handles to catboard shader programs
    final string vertexShader = getVertexShader(R.raw.vertex_shader);
    final string fragmentShader = getFragmentShader(R.raw.fragment_shader);

    //set handles to string shader programs
    final string stringVertexShader = getVertexShader(R.raw.string_vertex_shader);
    final string stringFragmentShader = getVertexShader(R.raw.string_fragment_shader);

    //compile catboard shader programs
    final int vertexShaderHandle = OpenGL_ShaderHelper.compileShader(GLES20.GL_VERTEX_SHADER, vertexShader);
    final int fragmentShaderHandle = OpenGL_ShaderHelper.compileShader(GLES20.GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER, fragmentShader);

    //compile string shader programs
    final int stringVertexShaderHandle = OpenGL_ShaderHelper.compileShader(GLES20.GL_VERTEX_SHADER, stringVertexShader);
    final int stringFragmentShaderHandle = OpenGL_ShaderHelper.compileShader(GLES20.GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER, stringFragmentShader);

    //create and link compiled shader programs to catboard and string program handle variables
    catBoardProgramHandle = OpenGL_ShaderHelper.createAndLinkProgram(vertexShaderHandle, fragmentShaderHandle,
            new string[]{"a_Position", "a_Color", "a_Normal", "a_TexCoordinate"});

    // Load images into Texture objects
    initializeTexture(cat);
    stringTexture = new OpenGL_TextureData(mActivityContext, R.drawable.texture_brass_string);
}

//sets up orthographic projection matrix
public void setupOrtho(int width, int height){
    // Create a new perspective projection matrix. The height will stay the same
    // while the width will vary as per aspect ratio.
    final float ratio = (float) width / height;
    final float near = -20.0f;
    final float far = 20.0f;
    final float screenWidth = 6.0f;
    final float left = -screenWidth/2.0f;
    final float right = -left;
    final float bottom = screenWidth/(2.0f*ratio);
    final float top = -bottom;
    orthoTop = top;
    orthoBottom = bottom;
    Matrix.orthoM(mProjectionMatrix, 0, left, right, bottom + scroller.getCurrentValue(), top+scroller.getCurrentValue(), near, far);
}

@Override
public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 glUnused, int width, int height)
{
    frameHeight = height;
    frameWidth = width;
    GLES20.glViewport(0, 0, width, height);         //Set the OpenGL viewport to the same size as the surface.
    // Create a new perspective projection matrix. The height will stay the same
    // while the width will vary as per aspect ratio.
    setupOrtho(width, height);

    //Configure rectangles for sprites
    float heightBound = 6.0f*catBoardTexture.imageHeight/catBoardTexture.imageWidth; //6*h*w = (width of ortho projec. * aspect ratio)
    RectF catBoardBounds = new RectF(-3.0f, orthoTop, 3.0f, heightBound + orthoTop);

    //Configure Sprites!
    //scale,fit,repeat vertically, fill
    catBoard = new OpenGL_SpriteClass(catBoardTexture.textureID, catBoardTexture.imageWidth, catBoardTexture.imageHeight, catBoardBounds,0);
}
```

}

**OpenGL SpriteClass**

```
public class OpenGL_SpriteClass {
FloatBuffer positionBuffer;
FloatBuffer textureBuffer;
RectF _frame;
int _textureID;
//SizeF _textureSize;
Float textureWidth, textureHeight;

int mode; // TODO: use enumeration

boolean valid;

//public OpenGL_SpriteClass(int textureID, SizeF textureSize, RectF frame) {
public OpenGL_SpriteClass(int textureID, float txWidth, float txHeight, RectF frame, int modeNum) {
    setTextureID(textureID);
    setTextureSize(txWidth, txHeight);
    setFrame(frame);
    setMode(modeNum);
}

public void bindTexture() {
    GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, _textureID);
}

public void setMode (int modeNum){
    valid = false;
    mode = modeNum;
    bindTexture();
    if (modeNum == 2){
        GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GLES20.GL_REPEAT);
        GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GLES20.GL_REPEAT);
    }
    else{
        GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GLES20.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
        GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GLES20.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    }
}

public void setFrame(RectF frame) {
    // TODO: check if _frame is different from frame and invalidate
    valid = false;
    _frame = frame;
}

public void setTextureID(int textureID) {
    valid = false;
    _textureID = textureID;
}

/* public void setTextureSize(SizeF size) {
     // TODO: check if _textureSize is different from size and invalidate
     valid = false;
     _textureSize = size;
 }*/
public void setTextureSize(float textWidth, float textHeight) {
    // TODO: check if _textureSize is different from size and invalidate
    valid = false;
    textureWidth = textWidth;
    textureHeight = textHeight;
}

public FloatBuffer getPositionBuffer() {
    if(valid == false) {
        generateBuffers();
    }
    return positionBuffer;
}

public FloatBuffer getTextureBuffer() {
    if(valid == false) {
        generateBuffers();
    }
    return textureBuffer;
} ...}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OpenGL ES 2.0 locates sprites using screen-space ( – 1.0 to + 1.0) dimensions but draws them using pixel space dimensions.

Pass the screen height as a uniform to the point vertex shader and use that value to calculate `gl_PointSize`.

Accessing the screen height in pixels is simple in `onSurfaceChanged` but if you want ot do the same in `OnSurfaceCreated`, use the following `int`:

```
context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels
```

Thanks to Reinier for posting the way to get this height in [this blog.](http://androidblog.reindustries.com/a-real-opengl-es-2-0-2d-tutorial-part-6-screens-and-dimensions/)